# Jetpack Compose not taking the colorScheme

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I have an android app written in Jetpack Compose. I am trying to set Icon colors using the defined colorScheme in my app, but it's not working.

Below is my code.

Color.kt

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

val green = Color(0xFF61FF67)
```

Theme.kt

```
private val MesColorDark = darkColorScheme(
        primary = green,
        secondary = green,
        tertiary = green,
        surface = green
)

private val MesColorLight = lightColorScheme(
        primary = green,
        secondary = green,
        tertiary = green,
        surface = green
)

@Composable
fun MesTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val mesColorScheme =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        } else {
            if (darkTheme) MesColorDark else MesColorLight
        }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = mesColorScheme,
        typography = MesTypography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <!-- Status bar -->
    <color name="black30">#4D000000</color>
</resources>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="Platform.Theme.Mes" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Mes" parent="Platform.Theme.Mes" />

</resources>
```

Then I have an icon defined as such:

```
Icon(
imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Phone,
contentDescription = "Open navigation drawer",
tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
)
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you can see, this color has not been defined in the color scheme. Even if I use `surface`, `background` etc... it still doesn't become green

However, if i use this code instead:

```
Icon(
imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Phone,
contentDescription = "Open navigation drawer",
tint = Colors.Green
)
```

It changes to this:

[image]

Can someone please help on why the colorScheme is not working ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
val mesColorScheme = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
} else {
    if (darkTheme) DarkColorScheme else LightColorScheme
}
```

Please check the above code in Theme.kt file. Since you are using Android S or greater, dynamic color will be enabled. Please change that code like below.

```
val mesColorScheme = if (darkTheme) DarkColorScheme else LightColorScheme
```

Comment: I am using material3, so colors has been changed to colorScheme. And yes my root app is inside `MesTheme { }`

Comment: @MervinHemaraju Please check the updated answer. I verified it. It works.

Comment: Oh yeah this is working! But my app works from Q and above. If I understand correctly, your answer works for S and above. So how do i fix this ?

Comment: Only In the devices that are S or above will have [Dynamic Colors](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#dynamic_color_schemes)  enabled. In the older devices it will work fine. we are just disabling Dynamic colors for all the devices. So In all the devices, the colors will be as expected.

Comment: Ohh okay. What was the purpose of the dynamic colors then ? Why does google use that in the default project creation ?

Comment: Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#dynamic_color_schemes) to get an overview about the dynamic colors

Comment: Oh yeah I completely forgot about the new Material You! Thank you so much for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Add onPrimary like this

```
private val MesColorDark = darkColorScheme(
    primary = green,
    onPrimary = green,
    primaryContainer =green,
    onPrimaryContainer = green
)
```

Comment: Tried it and it's still not working...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Preview(apiLevel = 30, // The API level should be 30 or below for Jetpack Compose to pick the colors from the color schema.)
@Composable
    fun MyComposable() {
        MyTheme {....}
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, that took me some time to figure out. I'm providing my own colors and typography. The problem was that my typography references the colors from the theme.

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val isSystemInDarkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()
    val colors = if (isSystemInDarkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors
    val typography = getTypography()

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalColors provides colors,
        LocalTypography provides typography,
        ) {
            MaterialTheme(
                content = content,
                colors = colors
            )
        }
   }
```

when I changed it to this, it worked!

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val isSystemInDarkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()
    val colors = if (isSystemInDarkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalColors provides colors,
    ) {
        val typography = getTypography()
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalTypography provides typography,
        ) {
            MaterialTheme(
                content = content,
                colors = colors
            )
        }
    }
}
```